# Reset (or assign a value) to RadioButton in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, collection-radio-buttons

I have a slider and a RadioButton on a plot (very similar to the one show here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html).  If I change the Amp and Freq sliders and then hit reset, the plot goes back to its initial values.  However, if I change red to blue and then hit reset, it stays on blue.  How can I reset a RadioButton?  I use the following to reset the slider:

```
def resetplt(event)
    svalueM.reset()
```

where svalueM is defined as:

```
svalueM = Slider(slider_M, 'M', smin, smax, valinit=sinit)
```

Comment: Use `.set_active` to set the value to the initial one.

Comment: Ealier I thought I saw a comment referencing the above demo on my smartphone, but now that I am home I do not see that comment.  Can the poster of that comment please repost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`radio.set_active(0)`

to your reset function.

replace `0` with whatever value was set as `active=` in the creation of the RadioButtons

Comment: Thank you very much.  I look through MatPlotLib documentation and elsewhere and could not figure this out.  Can you tell me where one finds answers to such questions.  Thanks!

Comment: "how to reset" can be rephrased as "how to programmatically change the value of a radio button back to its original setting". [Looking at the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html?#matplotlib.widgets.RadioButtons) I can see that the initial value is set by the `active=` parameter in the constructor, and that there is a `set_active()` function that allows changing the selected button.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: So, I now added a checkbutton and want to reset it. The documentation says "set_active(self, index)" so I put CheckPar.set_active('2 Hz'',0) and I get the error TypeError: set_active() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. I'm confused.  Can you shed some light onto this.

Comment: You should probably ask another question because the situation is a bit more complicated for check boxes. But to solve your error, the syntax is `CheckPar.set_active(0)` to switch the state of the first check box